# MSCHART Line graph annotation position

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

Im wondering if anyone could help me with annotations im using in my MShart control.
I have a line chart, at certain data plots within this chart I have annotations.

```
RactangleAnnotation a = new RectangleAnnotation();
a.AnchorDataPoint = chart.Series["series1"].Points[i];
```

This places the annotation on my linechart at the position the data value is.
What I need is to display this annotation, possibly at the top of my chart, and draw a line from myh annotation to the dataValue.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get at the paint events in the Chart Control and use the DrawLine function.  Here's how to get at the paint events:

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2008/12/03/custom-annotate-your-charts.aspx

Comment: got it to work! ;D thanks for the nice link also that site is very neat! thank you v much Steve :)

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at the CalloutAnnotation. It provides a text entry area and draws an arrow to your data point. Here's an link to the sample files:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418